# Is there any optimization technique for DP with $f[i][j] = \min_{z<j}{f[i-1][z] + G[i][j-z]}$ where G[i] is increasing and positive?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a dynamic programming formula like
 $f[i][j] = \min_{z<j}{f[i-1][z] + G[i][j-z]}$ where $G[i][j]$ is positive and increasing along $j$ for all $i$s. Is there any optimization to make it faster than $O(N^3)$?

Comment: I know that if $optz[i][j] ≤ optz[i][j + 1]$ (e.g., when G[i] is a convex and increasing function) then we can use convex hull technique to optimize this formula, but it seems that this doesn't apply to this case where $G[i]$ can be arbitrarily increasing sequence.

Comment: Are you asking about this specific formula, or in general?  Your use of "like" makes me unsure which you are asking about.

Comment: @D.W. I'm referring to a set of DPs questions satisfying this formula.

Comment: Sorry; I can't understand that answer.